# PyInstaller OS Library Dependencies and Chroot

Tags: python, dependencies, pyinstaller, chroot

The PyInstaller [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html) states

> PyInstaller does not include libraries that should exist in any installation of this OS. For example in GNU/Linux, it does not bundle any file from /lib or /usr/lib, assuming these will be found in every system.

However the target environment may have installed a different version of the same set of libraries. Is there a way to find out all the OS libraries a pyisntaller generated binary depends on?

I created a binary `my_app/myapp` using pyisntaller. Then used `ldd` to list all the `.so` files it depends on, and copied all of them into the distribution directory. In my assumption, the resulting dist directory can be used as a root for a chroot environment. However it does not work.

From the `ldd` output:

```
# ldd my_app/my_app 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdddc67000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6d3342f000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f6d33212000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6d32e21000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6d3384e000)
```

It looks only these libraries are required dependents:

```
# ls -l lib
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  170960 Apr 16  2018 ld-2.27.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2030544 Apr 16  2018 libc-2.27.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      12 Apr 16  2018 libc.so.6 -> libc-2.27.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14560 Apr 16  2018 libdl-2.27.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      13 Apr 16  2018 libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.27.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 May 23  2017 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  116960 May 23  2017 libz.so.1.2.11
```

When I run `chroot ./ /lib/ld-2.27.so /my_app/my_app`, the screen shows

```
[26499] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
[26499] LOADER: Cannot get fullpath for /my_app/my_app
[26499] LOADER: homepath is /my_app
[26499] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
[26499] LOADER: archivename is /my_app/my_app
[26499] LOADER: Extracting binaries
[26499] LOADER: Executing self as child
[26499] LOADER: set _MEIPASS2 to /my_app
[26499] LOADER: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my_app
[26499] LOADER: Registering signal handlers
[26500] Failed to exec: No such file or directory
```

Where the last line should be `[99] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x` and from there the program should continue.

I know chroot would work because it does when the whole `/` is copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `Failed to exec: No such file or directory` was due to the ld has to be at the path `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. Despite the actual file it points to is really `ld-2.27.so`:

```
ls -l /lib64/
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
```

Once that is fixed, a new error message makes more sense, pointing to a missing `libpthread...`.

Looked deeper into the PyInstaller internal, it packaged at least three other binary executables inside: A python interpreter, and two binaries for a bootloader. Thus run `ldd` on the python which the PyInstaller uses, and on those two bootloaders found under the site packages directory, it will be all the dependencies required. The above `libpthread...` is required by the python interpreter.

And the `ldd` output shows it wants the library files to be under `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` instead of `/lib/`.

The final content of `lib/` and `lib64/` are:

```
# ls -l lib
-rwxr-xr-x    170960 Apr 16  2018 ld-2.27.so
-rwxr-xr-x   2030544 Apr 16  2018 libc-2.27.so
lrwxrwxrwx        12 Apr 16  2018 libc.so.6 -> libc-2.27.so
-rw-r--r--     14560 Apr 16  2018 libdl-2.27.so
lrwxrwxrwx        13 Apr 16  2018 libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.27.so
lrwxrwxrwx        17 Sep 10 11:05 libexpat.so.1 -> libexpat.so.1.6.7
-rw-r--r--    202880 Sep 10 11:05 libexpat.so.1.6.7
-rw-r--r--   1700792 Apr 16  2018 libm-2.27.so
lrwxrwxrwx        12 Apr 16  2018 libm.so.6 -> libm-2.27.so
-rwxr-xr-x    144976 Apr 16  2018 libpthread-2.27.so
lrwxrwxrwx        18 Apr 16  2018 libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.27.so
-rw-r--r--     10592 Apr 16  2018 libutil-2.27.so
lrwxrwxrwx        15 Apr 16  2018 libutil.so.1 -> libutil-2.27.so
lrwxrwxrwx        14 May 23  2017 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11
-rw-r--r--    116960 May 23  2017 libz.so.1.2.11
lrwxrwxrwx         1 Feb 27 17:14 x86_64-linux-gnu -> .

# ls -l lib64
lrwxrwxrwx   32 Apr 16  2018 ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
```

This seems to have been working well.

This directory potentially can run on top of the bare metal of a kernel, without including other user space applications in the rootfs. It's becoming very interesting.

Comment: The libraries excluded in the build are listed by a variable named `_unix_excludes` in the pyinstaller file `PyInstaller/depend/dylib.py`. Comment out lines in the fill will allow those libraries to be included. The variable is for Linux OS, other variables for other OS's are in the same file.